# Cs cart in admin new controller gives an error

Tags: php, controller, cs-cart

I want to develop a new page in admin panel of **CSCART**.I made a controller pincode.php and mode 'add' and create a tpl add.tpl in views.when a call 'admin.php?dispatch=pincode.add'. It gives an http error.

Controller(cscart\app\controllers\backend\pincode.php)

```
<?php
use Tygh\Registry;
if (!defined('BOOTSTRAP')) { die('Access denied'); }

if ($mode == 'add') {
    Registry::get('view')->display('views/pincode/add.tpl');
}
?>
```

View(cscart\design\backend\templates\views\pincode\add.tpl):

```
 <form action="" method="post" name="add_form">
   <input type="text" name="pincode" />
   <input type="text" name="city" />
   <input type="text" name="state" />
 </form>
```

**When I put echo die in controller it shows the echo content.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is better to create a new add-on called pincode ( you can generate one [here](http://www.cs-cart.ie/cs-cart-addon-builder/) ) in this whay you will be upgrade ready ;)

## add controller file

```
cscart/app/addons/pincode/controllers/backend/pincode.php
```

## with content

```
<?php
/*
 * © 2015 Hungryweb
 * 
 * @website: www.hungryweb.net
 * @support: support@hungryweb.net
 *  
 */

if ( !defined('BOOTSTRAP') ) { die('Access denied'); }

use Tygh\Registry;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    fn_trusted_vars (
        'pincode'
    );

    if ($mode == 'update') {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['pincode'])) {
            #add your code
            print_r($_REQUEST['pincode']);
            exit;
        }
     }
}

if ($mode == 'update') {

    $pincode = array();
    $pincode['pin'] = '';
    $pincode['city'] = '';
    $pincode['state'] = '';
    Registry::get('view')->assign('pincode', $pincode);

}
```

## add tpl file

```
cscart/design/backend/templates/addons/pincode/views/pincode/update.tpl
```

## with content (is better update mode then add )

```
{capture name="mainbox"}

<form action="{""|fn_url}" method="post" name="pincode_update_form" class="form-horizontal form-edit">

    {include file="common/subheader.tpl" title=__("information") target="#pincode_information_setting"}
    <div id="pincode_information_setting" class="in collapse">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="elm_pincode" class="control-label cm-required">{__("pincode_field")}:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="pincode[pin]" id="elm_pincode" size="55" value="{$pincode.pin}" class="input-large" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="elm_city" class="control-label cm-required">{__("city")}:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="pincode[city]" id="elm_city" size="55" value="{$pincode.city}" class="input-large" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="elm_state" class="control-label cm-required">{__("state")}:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="pincode[state]" id="elm_state" size="55" value="{$pincode.state}" class="input-large" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
  </div>

{capture name="buttons"}
     {assign var="hide_first_button" value=false}
     {assign var="hide_second_button" value=true}
    {include file="buttons/save_cancel.tpl" but_name="dispatch[pincode.update]" hide_first_button=$hide_first_button hide_second_button=$hide_second_button but_target_form="pincode_update_form"}
{/capture}

</form>

{/capture}

{capture name="sidebar"}
    <div class="sidebar-row">
        <h6>{__("pages")}</h6>
        <div class="nested-tree">
            Maybe you need ;)
        </div>
    </div>
{/capture}

{include file="common/mainbox.tpl" title=__('pincode_update') sidebar=$smarty.capture.sidebar sidebar_position="right" content=$smarty.capture.mainbox buttons=$smarty.capture.buttons adv_buttons=$smarty.capture.adv_buttons}
```

zip archive with this CS-Cart add-on can be downloaded from [here](https://www.hungryweb.net/downloads/cs-cart/addons/pincode-cs-cart-4.2.x-addon-1.0.zip)

I hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

Just rename add.tpl to update.tpl.
There is a code in the **fn.control.php** file:

```
if ($mode == 'add') {
    $tpl = 'update.tpl';
} elseif (strpos($mode, 'add_') === 0) {
    $tpl = str_replace('add_', 'update_', $mode) . '.tpl';
} else {
    $tpl = $mode . '.tpl';
}
```